# Getting user cookies using next.js

Tags: next.js, cookies, tailwind-css

I've created a custom login api that will save a jwt to the user's cookies when they sucesfully login. I'm trying to make it so that when a user logs in, the create account and login links wont get rendered. I cant figure out why my code isnt working, as of right now im just trying to console.log the user cookies but it shows as undefined even when I can see myself that the jwt is present in their cookies. Any ideas or help is appreciated:

header code:

```js
'use client';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'; 
export default function Header() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect is running...");
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const cookies = document.cookie;
      console.log("All cookies:", cookies);
      const token = cookies.split(';').find(cookie => cookie.trim().startsWith('token='));
      console.log("Token from cookies:", token);
      setIsLoggedIn(!!token);
    }
  }, []);
  
  

  return (
    <header className='bg-white border-b flex justify-between p-4'>
      <div className="flex items-center gap-6">
        <Link href={'/'}>FashionFinder </Link>
        <nav className='flex gap-4'>
          <Link href={'/about'}>About</Link>
          <Link href={'/contact'}>Contact</Link>
          <Link href={'/albums'}>Albums</Link>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <nav className='flex items-center gap-4'>
        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <Link href={'/logout'}>Sign Out</Link>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Link href={'/login'}>Sign In</Link>
            <Link href={'/register'}>Create Account</Link>
          </>
        )}
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}
```

login route.js:

```js
import { connect } from "@/dbConfig/dbConfig";
import User from "@/models/userModel";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import bcryptjs from "bcryptjs";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

connect()

export async function POST(request) {
  try{

    const reqBody= await request.json()
    const {email, password} = reqBody;
    console.log(reqBody)
    const lowercasedEmail = email.toLowerCase();

    //check if the user exists
    const user = await User.findOne({email: lowercasedEmail})
    if (!user){
      return NextResponse.json({error:"User does not exist"}, {status: 400})
    }

    //check if valid email format
    const isValidEmail = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(email);
    if (!isValidEmail) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: "Invalid email format" }, { status: 300 });
    }
  

    //check if the password is correct
    const validPassword = await bcryptjs.compare(password, user.password)
    if (!validPassword){
      return NextResponse.json({error: "Invalid password"}, {status:500})
    }
    //create token data
    const tokenData = {
      id: user._id,
      email: user.email
    }
    //create token
    const token = await jwt.sign(tokenData, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, {expiresIn: "1d"})

    const response = NextResponse.json({
      message: "Login successful",
      success: true
    })
    response.cookies.set("token", token, {
      httpOnly: true
    })
    return response;

  } catch (error){
    return NextResponse.json({error: error.message}, {status: 500})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cookie won't show up because the flag httpOnly is set to true. Javascript cannot read a httpOnly cookie. This is something you can test in your browser even.

Set cookie:

[image]

Read cookie:

[image]

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)